# What does the $(m,n)$ mean in context of $\mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation, modules, abelian-groups

On the section about the Hom sets of modules, Hungerford has an exercise that asks to show that
$$\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_m, \mathbb{Z}_n) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$$
and then in the next exercise he has

If $A,B$ are abelian groups and $m,n$ integers such that $mA = 0 = nB$, then every element of $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ has order dividing $(m,n)$.

What does $(m,n)$ mean in these contexts?

Comment: It means $gcd(n,m)$.

Comment: In number theory $\,(a,b)\,$ is commonly used to denote $\,\gcd(a,b)\,$ (same as the ideal $\,(a,b) = (a) + (b) $ in PIDs, so one can give [unified proofs](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) for ideals and gcds using this notation) Also $\,\[m,n] = (m)\cap (n)\, $ is used for lcm, though that is less common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$.