# If $a|bc$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then $a|c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I read the proof of this theorem in Apostol's **Mathematical Analysis**.  It was not $100 \%$ clear so I re-did it in a way that makes more sense to me. Please tell me if this is an acceptable proof.

> - $a|bc \implies bc=ak$ for some integer $k$
> - $\gcd(a,b)=1 \implies 1 = ax + by \implies c = axc + byc$  for some integers $x$ and $y$.
> - Multiplying both sides of the first equation by $y$ we get $$bcy = aky$$
> - Substituting this into the second equation we get $$c = axc + (aky)$$
> - Factoring out $a$ we get $c = a(xc+ky)$ which implies that $a|c$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. That's a common way to present the proof using Bezout. How did the texbook proof differ?

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) for a comparison between the Bezout and gcd forms of the proof (and others).

Comment: Thank you very much.  The textbook had the same first two sentences and then went on to state that a|axc and a|byc so therefore a|c.  I did not understand how those two statements implied the third.

Comment: The implication is that since $a\mid axc$ and $a\mid byc$ then $a\mid (axc+byc)$. But that last one is just $c$. It's basically what you did, except they didn't go all the way to _factoring out_ the $a$.