# if $a\mid x$ and $b\mid x$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, prove $a\cdot b\mid x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

if $a\mid x$ and $b\mid x$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, prove that $a\cdot b\mid x$

Well, I've started by saying that $x = q_1a$ and $x = q_2b$, and I know that $a,b$ are prime numbers. And, I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Edit: The answer here is better than in the posts listed here

Comment: a and b need not be prime numbers. They are coprime. E.g. 6 and 7 are coprime, but not both primes.

Comment: $\quad\uparrow\quad$ Or $14$ and $15$ if you want an example where neither is prime. $\qquad$

Comment: For me the first thing that comes to mind is that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $a$ and $b$ have no prime factors in common, so in the prime factorization of $x$ the parts corresponding to $a$ and to $b$ are disjoint from each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x=ak=bl$ where $k$ and $l$ are integers. Since $\text{gcd}(a,b)=1$, there are also integers $r,s$ such that
$$
1=ra+sb.
$$
Then,
$$
x=rax+sbx=ra(bl)+sb(ak)=ab(rl+sk)
$$
proving that $ab|x$.

Comment: I knew that $1 = ra + sb$, but didn't know how to continue from there. but multiplying by $x$ solves this so easy :)

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS  The proof is more simple, more conceptual (and more general) if you use Euclid;s Lemma (or unique factorization) as in the other answers. For example those proofs work over certain polynomial rings whereas the above proof fails.

Answer (score 1):

If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $a$ and $b$ have no prime factors in common, so in the prime factorization of $x$ the parts corresponding to $a$ and to $b$ are disjoint from each other.

This is probably the simplest way to infer the desired conclusion from well known results, but as Bill Dubuque points out in comments, it may not be the simplest was to do it from scratch because it does not include a proof of the uniqueness of prime factorizations. That uniqueness itself takes some work to prove.

Comment: @OP Beware that it in some approaches this way might be circular since it is used to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, i.e. the *existance and uniqueness* of prime factorizations.

Answer (score 1):

By [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) $\, (\color{#c00}{a,b})=1,\,\ \color{#c00}a\mid \color{#c00}b\,(x/b)\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid x/b\,\Rightarrow\, ab\mid x\ $