# On inverting in non-UFDs

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, inverse, unique-factorization-domains

Suppose $n=ab=cd$ in an non-UFD where $a,b,c,d$ are irreducibles.

Do $c^{-1}\bmod a$, $c^{-1}\bmod b$, $d^{-1}\bmod a$, $d^{-1}\bmod b$ and $a^{-1}\bmod c$, $a^{-1}\bmod d$, $b^{-1}\bmod c$, $b^{-1}\bmod d$  exist?

If so can we find using any modification of Extended Euclidean Algorithm?

If not how to find them?

If we know $c^{-1}\bmod a$, $c^{-1}\bmod b$ can we get $c^{-1}\bmod ab$?

=========

I think the answer is negative.

For example in $\Bbb Z[i\sqrt{5}]$ it is negative. Since $(1-i\sqrt{5})^{-1}=\frac{1+i\sqrt5}6$ and $6$ is not invertible $\bmod 2$ or $\bmod 3$ yet $2\cdot3=(1+i\sqrt 5)(1-i\sqrt 5)$. I was not sure whether $2$ or $3$ were invertible $\bmod (1+i\sqrt{5})$ or $\bmod (1-i\sqrt{5})$.

But could there be examples where inverses exist (in quadratic case it generally seems negative because of the norm in denominator)?

May be there are cubic and higher order cases where we can expect the unexpected?

Comment: @EricWofsey updated I just want to know if we can do $c^{-1}\bmod b$?

Comment: @EricWofsey sorry clarified the query .. is it still no?

Comment: Can you write what your assumptions are more clearly?  You say you are in a "non-UFD", but what does that mean?  Are you assuming you are in an arbitrary integral domain?  Are $a$ and $b$ both supposed to not be associates of $c$ or $d$?

Comment: Euclidean domains are PIDs so UFDs, so what do you mean by the Euclidean algorithm in a non-UFD?

Comment: @EricWofsey I think the answer is negative. For example in $\Bbb Z[i\sqrt{5}]$ it is negative. Since $(1-i\sqrt{5})^{-1}=\frac{1+i\sqrt5}6$ and $6$ is not invertible $\bmod 2$ or $\bmod 3$ yet $2\cdot3=(1+i\sqrt 5)(1-i\sqrt 5)$. I was not sure whether $2$ or $3$ were invertible $\bmod (1+i\sqrt{5})$ or $\bmod (1-i\sqrt{5})$. But could there be examples where inverses exist (in quadratic case it generally seems negative because of the norm in denominator)?  May be there are cubic and higher order cases where we can expect the unexpected?

Comment: @BillDubuque you missed 'modification' and 'If not how to find them?'.

Comment: If $\,c^{-1}\!\pmod a$ exists then $\,(c,a) = 1\,$ so $\,c\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\,c\mid b\,$ by [Euclid's Lemma (in Bezout form).](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242). Therefore $\,c^{-1}\pmod b\ $ does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $a$ and $b$ are not associates of $c$ or $d$ so that we really do have two distinct factorizations of $n$, these inverses can never exist.  For instance if $c$ had an inverse mod $a$, then we would have $$d\equiv c^{-1}cd\equiv c^{-1}ab\equiv 0\pmod{a}$$ so $d$ is divisible by (and hence associate to) $a$, contrary to our assumption.  In the language of ring theory, what's going on is that $c$ and $d$ are zero-divisors in the quotient ring mod $a$, and zero-divisors can never be units (in a nonzero ring).

Comment: How about if $a=cu$ and $b=vd$ holds where $uv=1$?

Comment: Then $c^{-1}$ mod $a$ certainly doesn't exist, since $c$ is $0$ mod $a$, and similarly for many of the others.  Inverses like $c^{-1}$ mod $b$ may or may not exist.