# Prove that if $p(x)$ is irreducible, then $\langle p(x) \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $F[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Problem:**

Let $F$ be a field. Prove that if $p(x)$ is irreducible, then $\langle p(x) \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $F[x]$.

**Attempt:**

Let $d(x),a(x),p(x) \in F[x]$ and suppose $\text{gcd}[a(x), p(x)] = d(x)$. Then $d(x) \mid p(x)$. So $p(x) = d(x)c(x)$ for some $c(x) \in F[x]$. Because $p(x)$ is irreducible, either $d(x)$ or $c(x)$ is a constant.

If $d(x)$ is a nonzero constant in $F$, then $\langle p(x) \rangle = F[x]$ by [previous proof]* and $\langle p(x) \rangle$ is not maximal because it generates all of $F[x]$.

If $c(x)$ is a nonzero constant, then:
\begin{align*}
    p(x) &= d(x)c(x) \\
    p(x) &= d(x)c && \text{$c(x) = c$ is a constant}\\
    p(x)c^{-1} &= d(x)cc^{-1} \\
    p(x)c^{-1} &= d(x) \\
    d(x) &= p(x)c^{-1}
\end{align*}

Since $d(x) \mid a(x)$, we have that $a(x) = d(x)e(x)$ for some $e(x) \in F[x]$. Then:
\begin{align*}
    a(x) &= d(x)e(x) \\
    a(x) &= p(x)c^{-1}e(x) && \text{substitution}\\
    a(x) &= p(x)e(x)c^{-1}
\end{align*}

This implies that $a(x)$ is a multiple of $p(x)$.

**Questions:**

My understanding is that if $d(x)$ is a nonzero constant, then $\langle p(x) \rangle$ cannot be maximal because it generates the entire ring. But it also seems to me that $c(x)$ being a constant presents a contradiction.

Does $a(x)$ being a multiple of $p(x)$ present a contradiction, because $a(x)$ and $p(x)$ are relatively prime?

If not, how can I use that $c(x)$ being constant shows that $\langle p(x) \rangle$ is maximal?

**Second, guided attempt:**

Let $J$ be an ideal containing $\langle p(x) \rangle$ that isn't equal to $\langle p(x) \rangle$. Then there must exist a polynomial $a(x)$ that is in $J$ but not in $\langle p(x) \rangle$. We'll show that $J = F[x]$ using that $p(x)$ and $a(x)$ are relatively prime.

Let $d(x),a(x),p(x) \in F[x]$ and suppose $\text{gcd}[a(x), p(x)] = d(x)$. Then $d(x) \mid p(x)$. So $p(x) = d(x)c(x)$ for some $c(x) \in F[x]$. Because $p(x)$ is irreducible, either $d(x)$ or $c(x)$ is a constant.

By [previous proof]*, if $d(x)$ is a nonzero constant in $F$, then $J=F[x]$ and we are done.

If, on the other hand, $c(x)$ is a nonzero constant, then:
\begin{align*}
    p(x) &= d(x)c(x) \\
    p(x) &= d(x)c && \text{$c(x) = c$ is a constant}\\
    p(x)c^{-1} &= d(x)cc^{-1} \\
    p(x)c^{-1} &= d(x) \\
    d(x) &= p(x)c^{-1}
\end{align*}

Since $d(x) \mid a(x)$, we have that $a(x) = d(x)e(x)$ for some $e(x) \in F[x]$. Then:
\begin{align*}
    a(x) &= d(x)e(x) \\
    a(x) &= p(x)c^{-1}e(x) && \text{substitution}\\
    a(x) &= p(x)e(x)c^{-1}
\end{align*}

This implies that $a(x)$ is a multiple of $p(x)$, which is a contradiction, because $a(x)$ and $p(x)$ are relatively prime. Thus, $\langle p(x) \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $F[x]$.

* Previous proof: If $J$ is an ideal of $A$ and $J$ contains an invertible element $a$ of $A$, then $J = A$.

Comment: $(d) = (a,p) = (1)\,$ or $(p)$ by $(p)$ irred, so $\,a\not\in (p)\Rightarrow\, (a,p)=(1)\,$ so $(p)$ is maximal.

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ For principal ideals: $\ \rm\color{#0a0}{contains} = \color{#c00}{divides}$, $ $ i.e.  $(a)\supseteq (b)\iff a\mid b,\,$   thus having no proper containing ideal (maximal) is the same as having no proper divisor (irreducible), $ $ i.e.

$\\ \qquad\quad\begin{eqnarray} \\ (p)\,\text{ is maximal} 
&\iff&\!\!\ (p)\, \text{ has no proper } \,{\rm\color{#0a0}{container}}\,\ (d)\\
&\iff&\  p\ \ \text{ has no proper}\,\ {\rm\color{#c00}{divisor}}\,\ d\\
&\iff&\  p\ \ \text{ is irreducible}\\
\end{eqnarray}\ \ \ $

Comment: What is $a(x)$ in your proof? And how are you using it in the proof?

Comment: @JulianMejia An element in $F[x]$ such that $\text{gcd}[a(x), p(x)] = d(x)$.

Comment: My question was on the direction that what you need to prove is that $\langle a(x),p(x)\rangle$ is either $\langle p(x)\rangle$ or the entire $F[x]$.

Comment: Above I meamt $p$ irred, not $(p)$ irred. Do you grok my hinted proof? That's the conceptual essence of the matter here.

Comment: To be more explicit: your second line "If d(x) is a nonzero constant in F, then ⟨p(x)⟩=F[x] by [previous proof] and ⟨p(x)⟩ is not maximal because it generates all of F[x]." Is wrong.

Comment: @BillDubuque I understand your proof, it's my own that I'm having trouble with! But yes, your explanation is helpful.

Comment: @JulianMejia OK, I may have misunderstood the proof that this was based on. If $d(x)$ is a nonzero constant, then $\langle p(x) \rangle$ is maximal. If, on the other hand, $c(x)$ is a nonzero constant, then that would imply that $a(x)$ is a multiple of $p(x)$, which is a contradiction, because $a(x)$ and $p(x)$ are relatively prime. Thus, $d(x)$ must be the nonzero constant and $\langle p(x) \rangle$ must be maximal. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please explain the method you are using in your proof to prove that $(p)$ is max. There appears to be some confusion there.

Comment: For the record, that previous proof states that if $J$ is an ideal of $A$ and $J$ contains an invertible element $a$ of $A$, then $J = A$.

Comment: @Alex What  *method* are you using to show $(p)$ is max?  Is it: for any $a$ we have  $(a,p) = (p)\,$ or $(1)?\ $ We need to know that in order to debug the proof.

Comment: @BillDubuque Saying I have a method is probably overly generous. My strategy was to show that either c(x) or d(x) were constants, but I'm stuck on the fact that it if d(x) is a constant, then it's invertible in F, which implies that J = F[x], which implies that J is not maximal because it's equal to F[x]. If, on the other hand, c(x) is a constant, then a(x) is a multiple of p(x), which is a contradiction because a(x) and p(x) are relatively prime. There are obviously simpler ways to prove this, as you have shown. But I'm trying to finish up my own version here.

Comment: How do you propose to prove that $(p)$ is maximal, i.e. ___ $\Longrightarrow (p)$ is maximal? Please fill in the blank with the maximality criterion that you are attempting to apply in your proof (if your are using the definition of a maximal ideal then please tell us that definition).

Comment: I would recommend Algebra II (MA249) Lecture Notes from Warwick.

Comment: So, after reading the answer of Ehsaan, apparently your assumption was $(p(x))\subset I= (a(x))$ and you wanted to prove that $I=(p(x))$or $F[x]$? Is that right? This is what I was asking for, because in your proof, $(a(x))$ is not just a random polynomial.

Comment: @BillDubuque My strategy, now amended above, is to show that any ideal larger than $\langle p(x) \rangle$ must equal $F[x]$.

Comment: @JulianMejia You're correct. And I see now why you were asking that. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Alex Your 2nd proof is correct, but you should say why $\,d\in J.\,$  Said more succinctly the proof is as in my first comment, i.e. $\ (a,p) = (d)\,\Rightarrow\, d = \gcd(a,p) = 1$ or $p$ by $p$ irred, so $\,d = 1\,$ by $\,a\not\in (p).\ $ The proof in my 2nd comment is a bit clearer conceptually.

Comment: @BillDubuque Noted. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So the proof boils down to the fact that irred $\,p\nmid a\,\Rightarrow\, (p,a) = 1\,$ where we can read the pair notation as either a gcd or ideal. This connection between gcds and principal ideals in PIDs allows us to transfer divisibility intuition from $\Bbb Z$ to arbitrary PIDs, e.g. see [generalizations of Euclid' Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242)

Answer (score 1):

Every ideal of $F[x]$ is principal.  If $\langle p(x)\rangle$ is not maximal, then $p(x)$ must have a non-constant factor with a lower degree, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the contrary. Suppose that $<p(x)>=I$ (say)  is not a maximal ideal. Let $<q(x)>=J$ (say)  be another ideal property contained in $<p(x)>$, that is, $<p>\subset <q(x)>$. Then $q(x)=r(x)p(x)$ for some $r(x)\in F[x]$. Now consider the necessary cases.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the proof, maybe that will settle your questions?

If $(p(x))$ is not maximal, then there is an ideal $I$ containing it. We'll show $I=F[x]$ or $I=(p(x)).

Since $F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, we know $I=(f(x))$ for some polynomial $f(x)$. (This is probably where your argument involving $a(x)$, $d(x)$, and $c(x)$ comes in --- your $a(x)$ is my $f(x)$.)

Now the containment of ideals $(p(x))\subseteq (f(x))$ implies that $f(x)$ divides $p(x)$. But $p(x)$ is irreducible --- so this is only possible if $f(x)$ is a scalar multiple of $p(x)$, or if $f(x)$ is constant. These cases correspondingly imply $(f(x))=(p(x))$, or $(f(x))=F[x]$.