# If ${\rm ord}(a) = n$ where $n$ is odd, then ${\rm ord}(a^2) = n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

$\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}$
Exercise 10.D.4 from Pinter says:

> Let $a$ be any element of finite order of a group $G$. Prove the following:
> If $\ord(a) = n$ where $n$ is odd, then $\ord(a^2) = n$.

Here's an approach I took.

We'll be using the following from the same chapter:

**10.D.2**

> The order of $a^k$ is a divisor (factor) of the order of $a$.

**10.T5** (Theorem 5)

> Suppose an element $a$ in a group has order $n$. Then $a^t = e$ iff $t$ is a multiple of $n$.

Let's begin. By 10.D.2

$$\ord(a^2) \mid n$$

Let $m = \ord(a^2)$.

$$m \mid n$$

$$(a^2)^m = e$$

$$a^{2m} = e$$

By 10.T5

$$n \mid 2m$$

Due the the following rules:

$$even * even = even$$
$$even * odd  =  even$$
$$odd  * even = even$$
$$odd  * odd  = odd$$

$2m$ must be even.

But $n$ divides it so $n$ must be a factor of $m$.

Thus we have:

$$ m | n$$
$$  n | m$$

And so

$$m = n$$

**Question 1**: Is this an OK approach? I realize there are other approaches, but I wanted to explore one that only uses facts presented in or before this chapter in the book.

**Question 2**: [This page](http://pirun.ku.ac.th/%7Efscisut/417321/ex/order/EngPage2.html) also presents a similar solution.

He ends up with the following, like the above approach:

$$m | n$$
$$ n | 2m$$

At this point he states that:

> $\gcd(n, 2) = 1$ (because n is odd)
>
> Hence $n | m$

I understand the fact that $\gcd(n, 2) = 1$. But, how does he go from that fact to $n | m$?

Comment: You have been around for seven years and a half. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos There appears to be no explicit rule saying that questions must use LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question 1**: Is this an OK approach?

The argument that $\, o(a^2) =: m\mid n\mid 2m\,$ is correct. But the inference $\,n\mid m\,$ is not properly justified. To  use parity, note $\, n\mid 2m\,\Rightarrow\, nk = 2m\,$ is even hence $k$ is even, by $\,n\,$ odd. So cancelling $2$ yields $\, n(k/2) = m,\,$ so $\, n\mid m\,$ as claimed.

> At this point he states that:
>
> > `gcd(n, 2) = 1` (because n is odd).  Hence `n | m`
>
> I understand the fact that `gcd(n, 2) = 1`. But, how does he go from that fact to `n | m`?

Likely they apply Euclid's Lemma $\, \gcd(n,a)=1,\ n\mid am\,\Rightarrow\, n\mid m$ or it's generalization below.

**Theorem** $\, \ m\mid cx \iff\, \dfrac{m}{(m,c)}\ {\Large \mid}\ x.\ \ \,$  **Proof**  $\,\ $ Let $\ d = (m,c).\ $  Then

we deduce $\, \ m\mid cx \overset{{\rm cancel}\ d\!\!}\iff\ \color{#c00}{\dfrac{m}d}\ {\Large \mid}\ \color{#c00}{\dfrac{c}d}\:x\!\!\overset{\rm(EL)\!}\iff\! \dfrac{m}d\ {\Large \mid}\ x\,\ $ by [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) (EL),

because: $\,\ (m,c) = d\ \Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{\left(\dfrac{m}d,\,\dfrac{c}d\right)} = (m,c)/d = 1\ $ by the [GCD Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242)

Comment: I follow you up to $n(k/2) = m$. How does that imply $n | m$?

Comment: @dharmatech $\,k\,$ is even so $\,k/2\,$ is an integer. $\ \ $

Comment: Ok... Thank you for all the help. So very appreciative of your patience.

Answer (score 1):

It is a generalization of *Euclid's lemma* that:  $a\mid bc \land (a,b)=1\implies a\mid c$.  (This is sometimes called Gauß's lemma.)

Or, use the fact from the theory of cyclic groups:   $\vert a^k\vert=\dfrac{\vert a\vert}{\operatorname {gcd}(\vert a\vert,k)}$.

Comment: In your notation, I know that `a | bc` means "a divides bc". What does the `(a, b) = 1` part mean? (I looked up [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) and that article didn't clarify.)

Comment: It means $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.   I.e.  $\operatorname {gcd}(a,b)=1$.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help Chris!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, write $n=2k+1$.
Then $a=ea=a^n a=a^{n+1}=a^{2k+2}=(a^2)^{k+1}$.
Therefore
$
\langle a^2\rangle
\subseteq
\langle a\rangle
\subseteq
\langle a^2\rangle
$
and so
$
\langle a^2\rangle
=
\langle a\rangle
$.
Thus,
${\rm ord}(a^2) = |\langle a^2\rangle| = |\langle a\rangle| = {\rm ord}(a)$.