# Euclid's Lemma in the proof that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not euclidean

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

In proving, I induced that $3\gamma + (2+\sqrt{-5})\delta=1$. Textbook says that multiplying both sides by $2-\sqrt{-5}$ implies $2-\sqrt{-5}$ is multiple of 3. I don't know why. Can you explain the calculation.

Comment: $(2+\sqrt{-5})(2-\sqrt{-5})=9=3×3$.

Comment: Thank you for finding my mistake! You have great insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you multiply both sides by $2 - \sqrt{-5}$ you get

$$ \begin{align} (2 - \sqrt{-5}) \cdot 3 \cdot \gamma + (2 - \sqrt{-5}) \cdot (2 + \sqrt{-5}) \delta &= 2 - \sqrt{-5} \\
(2 - \sqrt{-5}) \cdot 3 \cdot \gamma + 3 \cdot 3 \delta &= 2 - \sqrt{-5} \\
3\cdot ((2 - \sqrt{-5}) \cdot \gamma + 3 \delta) &= 2 - \sqrt{-5} \end{align}$$

From the first to the second line we use $(2 - \sqrt{-5})(2 + \sqrt{-5}) = 4+5 = 9 = 3 \cdot 3$.

Comment: Thank you for calculation, I noticed my mistake looking yours.

Comment: @Sinaps It's just the proof  of Euclid's Lemma in this case - see my answer. That's the way you should view it *conceptually*.

Answer (score 0):

It's an instance of  Euclid's Lemma. Let $\,w = 2\!+\!\sqrt{-5}.\,$ so $\,\bar w = 2\!-\!\sqrt{-5}.\,$ Then we have

$$ \overbrace{\gcd(\color{#c00}{3,w})=1}^{\text{by Bezout equation}},\ \ \color{#c00}3\mid \overbrace{\color{#c00}w\:\!\bar w}^{\large 9}\,\overset{\rm\color{#0a0}{EL}}\Longrightarrow\, 3\mid \bar w,\, \ \ \text{by $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{EL}=$ Euclid's Lemma}\qquad$$

The hinted proof is *precisely* the [common (Bezout-based) proof of Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) in this instance. Of course it is better *conceptually* to invoke this *fundamental* property (Euclid's Lemma) *by name* rather than repeat its proof inline when applying it.