# Fake proof: in a commutative ring with no nonzero zero divisors, all irreducibles are prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, fake-proofs

When I was working on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4643275/alternative-ways-of-showing-that-x2-1-is-prime-in-mathbbzx) earlier today, I made up a superficially-reasonable-sounding non-theorem *in a commutative ring with no zero divisors, all irreducibles are prime.* The correct theorem is: in a *GCD domain*, all irreducibles are prime, as mentioned by Bill Dubuque in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4643275/alternative-ways-of-showing-that-x2-1-is-prime-in-mathbbzx#comment9801831_4643275) and ultimately [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27014/euclids-lemma-for-polynomials/27017#27017).

The fake theorem is simply not true since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ has non-prime irreducibles (6 factors as a product of two irreducibles in two ways, as $2 \cdot 3$ and $(1 + \sqrt{-5})(1 - \sqrt{-5})$) **and** no zero divisors.

My original post didn't make sense, as Arturo Magidin pointed out in the comments. The thing I was trying to prove really was false and I demonstrated it with the example I chose.

So, the **fake proof below is definitely fake**.

However, I think it is an interesting fake. It seemed correct (or at least plausible) to me half an hour ago and I'm curious which step is wrong or unjustified.

---

I'm defining an integral domain as a ring with no nonzero zero divisors. There are [some other equivalent definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain#Definition).

##### Fake Theorem: In all commutative rings with no nonzero zero divisors, all irreducible elements are prime.

Fake Proof:

Let $R$ be a ring with no nonzero zero divisors.

If $R$ is trivial it has no irreducible elements and we're done.

Let $a$ be an irreducible element of $R$ and let $(a)$ be its ideal as usual.

I will now show that $R/(a)$ is an integral domain and thus $a$ is prime.

I will start with a *general product* of two elements in $R/(a)$ that equals zero in $R/(a)$, expressed as representatives in $R$ of their corresponding equivalence classes, and then show that at least one of the products must be equivalent to zero in $R/(a)$. I assume a normal form property of $(c+da)$ and $(e+ha)$ where the first term is $0$ if the sum as whole is a multiple of $a$. For example $(a + 2a)$ is not in normal form, but the equivalent expression $(0 + 3a)$ is in normal form.

Suppose $(c+da)(e + ha) = ga$ where $a \nmid c$ and $a \nmid e$ (since $(c+da)$ and $(e+ha)$ are in normal form).

Since $a$ is irreducible, it also holds that $c \nmid a$ and $e \nmid a$.

$$ (c+da)(e + ha) \\ ce + eda + cha + dhaa \\ ce + (ed + ch + dha)a  $$

Since $a$ is irreducible and $ce | a$ must hold in order for the product to be zero in $R/(a)$, it follows that $ce = 0$.

Thus $c$ is $0$ or $e$ is $0$, by our hypothesis that $R$ was an integral domain initially.

$ga$ factors as $(c+da)(e+ha)$, and at least one of $c$ and $e$ must be zero, so at least one of $c+da$ and $e+ha$ must be equivalent to zero in $R/(a)$.

Thus $R/(a)$ is an integral domain, since any pair of elements that multiplies to zero contains at least one element that is zero.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yeah. you're right. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I misremembered a result and then tried to prove it. It is *GCD domains* where all irreducibles are prime. I also didn't notice the inconsistency that you pointed out. I converted this question into a fake proof question.

Comment: In order for the product to be zero in $R/(a)$, you must have $a|ce$ and not $ce|a$.

Comment: You have an example, so all you have to do is run your argument through the explicit example to find places where the argument does not hold. Using $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, $a=2$, $c=1+\sqrt{-5}$, $d=1-\sqrt{-5}$, $d=h=0$, your claim that $ce\mid 2$ is backward. But once you get to $2\mid ce$, the irreducibility of $2$ doesn't give you anything.